# How can I make all the lines of a very big file the same length in java?

Tags: java

I have a very big file. The length of the longest line of my file is 9.

I want to read my file with RandomAccessFile and be able to seek to the specific line.

How can I make the length of the lines of my file the same?

It will be great if you help me with the sample code.

Comment: How big is a very big file? If you are talking about a few 100MBs, you may be able to load the file into memory, and is its less than 2GB you can memory map the file into memory.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure you get the longest line you'd need to read them all and get their length.
Assuming this is a text file you could use the BufferedReader#readLine() method.

When you have read the lines you need to write the file again.
The easiest way would be to store the lines in a list while reading and then write them to the file afterwards adding spaces as needed. To do this you could use PrintWriter#format()  like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = .... ;//excercise for you
String format = "%" + maxlength + "s";
for(String line : lines)
{
  pw.format( format, line );
}
```